# Azure Data Factory pipeline copy activity slow?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline with 4 copy activities scheduled. I have just created one copy activity where the input and output dataset are azure SQl, the source table has more than 100 000 records and it takes a long time to copy in destination.

Copy activity timeout interval is 1 hr so it always timeout and the records copied on destination is just 50000. I have noticed that because of one columns which is "description" column the process is taking time.

Comment: To add, same issue is faced when uploading documents to azure index from azure sql db for 50000 records it takes 1.5 hrs, well I have other index with more than 3 lakh records which takes 10 mins to upload.